# REST request argument Validation In Router Function

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In Spring controller approach, We could do REST request argument validation using `@Valid` with Something like this

```
@PostMapping(REGISTER)
  public ResponseEntity<SomeData> registerSomeData(@RequestBody @Valid final SomeData someData) {
    ...................
  }



public class SomeData {

  @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
  private String firstname;

  @Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 10)
  private Integer customerID;

  @NotNull
  private Customer customer;
}
```

If the request doesn't match these contraints, then Spring framework would throw Bad Request Exception(400).

With Spring5 router functions, I don't understand how we can do this, because we can't give `@Valid` in router functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use annotation-based validation with (functional) Spring Webflux. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46540102).

If you absolutely need annotation-based validation, you should know that you can keep using the traditional Spring MVC with Spring 5 (or non-functional Webflux).

Comment: Correction: with Webflux functional. Webflux with its annotation mode supports annotation based validation.

Comment: @BrianClozel oops! you are right of course. I wrote that too fast.

Answer (score 4):

It's mildly irritating that this useful functionality does not seem to have been carried over into the functional world but it's really not too hard to implement the validation step yourself. Here's how.

Create a bean to perform the validation:

```
@Component
public class RequestValidator {

  @Inject
  Validator validator;

  public <T> Mono<T> validate(T obj) {

    if (obj == null) {
      return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException());
    }

    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = this.validator.validate(obj);
    if (violations == null || violations.isEmpty()) {
      return Mono.just(obj);
    }

    return Mono.error(new ConstraintViolationException(violations));
  }
}
```

Now in your handler function include a step that performs the validation. In this example the `FindRequest` class is a JSON domain model class that contains validation annotations such as `@NotEmpty` and `@NotNull` etc. Adapt how you construct the `ServerResponse` based on this fictitious example that calls a reactive data repository.

```
  @Component
  public class MyHandler {

    @Inject
    RequestValidator validator;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> findAllPeople(ServerRequest request) {

      return request.bodyToMono(FindRequest.class)
          .flatMap(this.validator::validate)
          .flatMap(fr -> ServerResponse
              .ok()
              .body(this.repo.findAllByName(fr.getName()), Person.class));
    }
  }
```

The same approach can be used to extend the functionality to handle `Flux` as well as `Mono`.

Comment: Hi, 
this should be the accepted response, you saved my day.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created `GeneralValidator` class which works `javax.validation.Validator`

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GeneralValidator {

    private final Validator validator;

    private <T> void validate(T obj) {

        if (obj == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = this.validator.validate(obj);
        if (violations != null && !violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }


     /**
     * @param obj object we will validate
     * @param next Publisher we will call if don't have any validation hits
     */
    public <T> Mono<ServerResponse> validateAndNext(T obj, Mono<ServerResponse> next) {
        try {
            validate(obj);
            return next;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest()
                    .body(new ErrorResponse("Request body is empty or unable to deserialize"), ErrorResponse.class);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
            return ServerResponse.badRequest()
                    .body(new ValidationErrorResponse(
                            "Request body failed validation",
                            ex.getConstraintViolations()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(v -> "Field '%s' has value %s but %s"
                                            .formatted(v.getPropertyPath(), v.getInvalidValue(),v.getMessage()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    ), ValidationErrorResponse.class);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```java
...
.POST("/", req -> req.bodyToMono(RequestObject.class)
        .flatMap(r -> validator.validateAndNext(r,routeFunction.execute(r)))
)
...
```

`routeFunction.execute`:

```java
public @NotNull Mono<ServerResponse> execute(RequestObject request) {
//handling body
}
```