# Reactive custom constraint validator in spring webflux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, bean-validation

I'm trying to write a custom ConstraintValidator which does a mongodb lookup using spring-webflux and spring-data reactive mongo.

In traditional spring webmvc, one would create a) an annotation and b) implement a custom ConstraintValidator, then annotate the `@RequestBody` with `@Valid`, and spring webmvc would
call the validator and reject the request with status code 400 if the validation result is false.

However when using the same approach in spring webflux, i seem to be forced to implement the custom constraint validator in a blocking way, which does not fit the reactive model of spring webflux. Example (simplified for brevity):

```java
public class UserPasswordValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUserPassword, UpdateUserPasswordDto> {

  @Resource
  private ReactiveUserRepository reactiveUserRepo;

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(UpdateUserPasswordDto userPasswordDto,
                         ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    // This is a blocking call. How can this be done in webflux?
    UserEntity user = reactiveUserRepo.findByUuid(userPasswordDto.getUuid()).block();


    if (!oldPasswordIsCorrect(userPasswordDto.getCurrentPassword(), user.getPasswordHash())) {
      context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
      context
          .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Incorrect current password")
          .addConstraintViolation();
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

}
```

Is there a way to do custom validation which needs a database lookup in spring webflux in a non-blocking way?

Comment: right now, there is not reactive  implementation on spring. here you could see a workaround based on spring doc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508618/spring-5-webflux-functional-endpoints-how-to-perform-input-validation

Comment: from what I see this is user authentication rather than password validation, so in my opinion you have to do this in the controller or the service layer